# Hand emoji Here has extra space, how can I solve this with CSS elegantly?

Tags: html, css, emoji

[image]

```css
p {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span></span>
  <span>Here</span>
  <span></span>
</p>
```

As you can see, the left emoji hand has extra empty space.

Currently, I add `padding-left: 0;` `padding-right: 5px;` to the center string.

But is there any other way or CSS property that can solve this?

[image]

My Browser is Chrome 80, there is actually a little extra space.

Although one line will remove space, but the problem still stands:

[image]

Using Pseudo class is not helping either, notice that there is still not line up

[image]

Comment: I've updated the screenshot, it really has a little extra space.

Comment: `p{font-size: 0;}span{font-size: 16px;}`

Comment: @Theraot left and right white space are removed, so the question still stands, it's not line up.

Answer (score 3):

I did a lot of cheating but this seems to work

```css
p {
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: -6px;
}
.letters{
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  padding-left: 0.35em;
}
```

```html
<p>
  
  <span class="letters">Here</span>
  
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

The emojis are really just decoration, not content. Use psuedo elements and the problem is solved.

```css
p {
  font-size: 16px;
}

p > span::before{
  content: '';
}

p > span::after{
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>Here</span>
</p>
```

Comment: The question still stands, I've updated the screenshot.

Comment: Hard to tell from pictures of code but it looks like you have white space next to the emojis in your css.

Answer (score -1):

This is because of the horizontal element（span）, not the emoji

set p element `font-size: 0`  or let all span tag  in one line

[image]

Comment: https://www.zhangxinxu.com/wordpress/2012/04/inline-block-space-remove-%e5%8e%bb%e9%99%a4%e9%97%b4%e8%b7%9d/

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: One line is not working, I've updated the screenshot